# R - Run nested loop in the same incremental sequence

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach, nested-loops

I'm relatively new to R and have a problem with a nested loop where I am trying to get the nested loop and parent loop to run at the same incremental sequence.

What we need is: 
for (i in 1:40),
when i = 1 -> run calculations -> run nested loop to summarise 
repeat for i = 2 until 40

Below is an illustration of what I'm trying to script:

```
for (i in 1:10) {# calculations...

   for (j in 1:10) {# calculations }

   # continue with other calculations}
```

In short, I'm trying to get "i" and "j" to loop in incrementally in sync with each other i.e. when i = 1, j = 1, and repeat when i = 2, j = 2. I've tried using foreach() but not sure how to apply the function.

The error message I am getting is: Error: Unknown column `COLUMN_NAME_2`

Appreciate any help on this! thank you!

Comment: You want j to always have the same value as i? If that's the case, it seems you don't need a second loop, just use i every time you'd use j. If that's not the case, then your question is not clear to me. Maybe you could edit to clarify?

Comment: @Bkeeks, This is pretty confusing. As pointed out,  if `i` and `j` are always the same, you don't need both of them, just use `i` everywhere. Or, if you still feel you want both, put `j = i` as the first line in the loop. If you want something to happen repeatedly inside the loop, maybe you use `j` as a counter, but still use `i` inside the inner loop. Or maybe `replicate` does what you want... it's hard to say with what you've provided.

Comment: But this really feels like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/173584). We don't need to know everything, but a bit more context about your goal, as well as a small sample input and desired output would go a long way to clarifying your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, although I'm not totally sure, since there isn't a reproducible piece of code (typically good to include those, just FYI), that you could simply use i (or j) for both purposes. For example,

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
b <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)

for (i in 1:4) {
  print(a[[i]])
  print(b[[i]])
}
```

There should be no need for a nested loop if the indexes are always the same.